# Fact Aggr. Type

Tags: iccube

When defining a hierarchy you can specify the `Fact Aggr. Type` as "Member and Ancestors" or "Member only".

In my understanding "Member and Ancestors" looks like a double count (or a triple count if the hierarchy has three levels).

As this is the default, my understanding is probably wrong. Do you have an small example of both cases?

```
Country City     Qty
Swiss   Geneva     2
Swiss   Lausanne   3
France  Lyon       4
France  Ferney     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are not counted several times:

**Member and Ancestors (the default) :** a member aggregates the facts defined for himself and his descendants.

**Member only:** a member aggregates the facts defined for himself only.

Let's do an example, for a dimension

```
 2013
    2013 Q1
    2013 Q2
    2013 Q2
```

and for facts that bind all levels of the date dimension :

```
  date    value
  2013      3      'not common but it was make the difference
  2013 Q1   1
  2013 Q2   2
  2013 Q3   2
```

The value for ( [2013],[Value] ) will be

**Member and Ancestors:** 8  (3+1+2+2)

**Member only:** 3  (we ignore the children)

This is handy is a hierarchy does not aggregate his children. You can see this as a 'fake' hierarchy

Comment: Yes, that's what I've understood from the tip-tool. But I still do not see the difference. I've edited my question to add an example. However on [Country], [Qty] will give me (5, 9) in both cases, no? What is it I miss?

Comment: add example, hope it helps

Comment: Hey, you mean icCube **can** handle missing values. That's cute, statistics departments are full of totals which are "official" but nobody knows anymore how it was computed 20 years ago, probably from countries that do not exists any more.